# Delete data after save inside modal bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

I have 2 pb to resolve with my form inside modal bootstrap 3

First : My data is saved twice
Second : When I save a data how to delete the data in input and textarea inside myform or if I reload the modal

Thanks

**first : catagories.php ==> call a modal**

```
   <style>
      .modal-dialog {
        width: 900px!important;
      }
    </style>

    <a data-toggle="modal" href="<?php echo FILENAME_MANUFACTURERS_POPUP;?>" data-target="#myModal"><?php echo osc_image (DIR_WS_ICONS . 'create.gif', TEXT_CREATE) ?></a>
   <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
           <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-body"><div class="te"></div></div>
           </div> <!-- /.modal-content -->
         </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
       </div><!-- /.modal -->

**second : inside my modal :manufacturers_popup.php**


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <form name="ajaxform" id="ajaxform" action="manufacturers_popup_ajax.php" method="post">
    <input> .......</input>
    <textarea>........</textarea>
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ext/javascript/bootstrap/js/bootstrap_ajax_form.js" /></script>
```

**third : my ajax files : bootstrap_ajax_form.php**

```
 $(document).ready(function()  {
    $("#simple-post").click(function()   {
      $("#ajaxform").submit(function(e) {
        $("#simple-msg").html("<img src='loading.gif'/>");
        var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
        var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
        $.ajax(  {
          url : formURL,
          type: "POST",
          data : postData,
          success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)  {
            $("#simple-msg").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">'+data+'</code></pre>');
          },
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)  {
            $("#simple-msg").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">AJAX Request Failed<br/> textStatus='+textStatus+', errorThrown='+errorThrown+'</code></pre>');
          }
        });
        e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
        e.unbind();
      });
      $("#ajaxform").submit(); //SUBMIT FORM
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Several things wrong here.

A submit handler will bind to the submit event of the form, you don't need to do it inside a click handler for the submit button.

You don't want to trigger the submit the way you are doing , that is what is causing the second save. WHen you click on a submit button inside a form, it will automatically trigger the form submit.

Try it this way:

```
$(function () {

    $("#ajaxform").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action do this first in case any errors thrown in code   

         var form = this;

        $("#simple-msg").html("<img src='loading.gif'/>");
        var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
        var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
        $.ajax({
            url: formURL,
            type: "POST",
            data: postData,
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $("#simple-msg").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">' + data + '</code></pre>');

                /* cleanup now */
                form.reset()

            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $("#simple-msg").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">AJAX Request Failed<br/> textStatus=' + textStatus + ', errorThrown=' + errorThrown + '</code></pre>');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. 

Works ,ow at 98% but I have again just a problem

My textarea is not deleted, I use ckeditor.

Do you have a solution  for that ?
Tk

Comment: I am zero in jquery to insert that in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

To clear your form Data you can use the below function

```
function clearFormFields(div){
        $('#'+div).find('input:text, input:hidden, input:password, input:file, select, textarea').val('');
        $('#'+div).find('input:radio, input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');
}
```

Add this function to your JS, and in your case you can call `clearFormFields("ajaxform")` when ever you want to clear the form fields

In case, If you need to clear your form data on every time hiding the Modal, you can bind it on your Bootstrap modal as

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden', function () {
    clearFormFields("ajaxform");  
})
```

see the other events on a Bootstrap modal [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage)

In case the above function didn't clear your CKeditor text field, you can use the CKEditor API method `setData` see the detailed documentation [here](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#setData)

Good Day

Comment: Thank, Is it possible to include this script inside the script below charlietfl ? It work but I quit the modal with your script. Not the same case with the script below but the textearea of ckeditor is not deleted. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @loicrichard Did you tried with the `setData` method mentioned in CKeditor documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks for all orientation.
I found the solution

```
$(function () {
  $("#ajaxform").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action do this first in case any errors thrown in code
    var form = this;


    $("#simple-msg").html("<img src='images/icons/loadingAnimation.gif'/>");
    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
    var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
    $.ajax({
      url: formURL,
      type: "POST",
      data: postData,
      success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $("#simple-msg").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">' + data + '</code></pre>');
/* clear ckeditor instance */
        for(k in CKEDITOR.instances){
          var instance = CKEDITOR.instances[k];
            instance.setData( '' );
        }
// cleanup now
       form.reset()
      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $("#simple-msg").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">AJAX Request Failed<br/> textStatus=' + textStatus + ', errorThrown=' + errorThrown + '</code></pre>');
      }
    });
  });
});
```